# Make a div scroll with page only in a certain place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can it be made so that a div scrolls with the page but only in a certain area of the page?

I can't work out how to do this with CSS for only part of the page, I think javascript may be the only option.

For e.g. There's three sections of a page, **Top**, **Middle** and **Bottom**.

There's a right floated div which should scroll with the user in the middle section and stop scrolling to be 'left in place' at the top of the **middle** section as well as the bottom of the **middle** section.

```css
#Top {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
#Middle {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
#Bottom {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
#scrolling-section {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="Top">
</div>
<div id="Middle">
  <div id="scrolling-section">
    This box should scroll along the green section but 'cut-off' and stop scrolling at the top and bottom of the green section
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Bottom">
</div>
```

JSFiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1d2a1Lc/)

Comment: Hi, you will need javascript, if you are using Bootstrap there is afix which is under the javascript section or you will need possibly code custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here you have solution using jquery:

1. Listen to the `scroll` event and calculate how much the `scrolling-section` goes outside the `Middle` section while scrolling up / down.
2. Added `position: relative` to the `scrolling-section`.
3. Adjust the position of the `scrolling-section` accordingly.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var wrapper = $('#Middle');
  var box = $('#scrolling-section');

  var offsetTop = - wrapper.offset().top + $(window).scrollTop();
  var offsetBottom = wrapper.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() + wrapper.outerHeight() - box.outerHeight();

  if (offsetBottom > 0 && offsetTop < 0) {
    box.css({
      'top': 0
    });
  } else if (offsetBottom > 0 && offsetTop > 0) {
     box.css({
      'top': offsetTop + 'px'
    });
  } else {
    box.offset({
      'top': $(window).scrollTop() + offsetBottom
    });
  }

});
```

```css
#Top {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
#Middle {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
#Bottom {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
#scrolling-section {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Top">
</div>
<div id="Middle">
  <div id="scrolling-section">
    This box should scroll along the green section but 'cut-off' and stop scrolling at the top and bottom of the green section
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Bottom">
</div>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Some Javascript is needed in order to read the point where you want to change the state of the div you wish to address. You can do this with the `getBoundingClientRect()` method. I have worked out a fiddle that will show you.
What happens is that you read the position of #Middle. I have added an input field that shows you the value. The change will be when the position hits zero. You then change the CSS properties of the #scrolling-section.

You will see some added readings of the element to ensure that it can be positioned in place and will keep its original width;

```js
var scrollposition = document.getElementById("Middle");
var scrollsection = document.getElementById("scrolling-section");
var scrollsection_offsetLeft = scrollsection.offsetLeft;
var scrollsection_width = scrollsection.offsetWidth;


var valy = document.getElementById("posy");


window.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) {
  valy.value = scrollposition.getBoundingClientRect().y || scrollposition.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  if (valy.value <= 0) {
    scrollsection.style.position = "fixed";
    scrollsection.style.top = "0px";
    scrollsection.style.left = scrollsection_offsetLeft + "px";
    scrollsection.style.width = scrollsection_width + "px";
  } else {
    scrollsection.style.position = "static";
    scrollsection.style.top = "auto";
    scrollsection.style.left = "auto";
  }
}, false)
```

```css
#posy {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#Top {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
#Middle {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
#Bottom {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
#scrolling-section {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="posy" />
<div id="Top">
</div>
<div id="Middle">
  <div id="scrolling-section">
    This box should scroll along the green section but 'cut-off' and stop scrolling at the top and bottom of the green section
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Bottom">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my mobile but if you add

```
#scrolling-section {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  height: 150px;
  right: 8px;
}
```

This will scroll with the page but really there will need to be an event listener that will trigger when #scrolling-section appears on the screen possibly adding the attribute position:fixed; then another event listener when the #bottom appears calculates the size of #middle set margin-top & position:absolute; hope this helps point in the right direction.